# Call exe in Inno Setup uninstall

Tags: inno-setup, uninstallation, pascal

I have an issue with the Inno Setup uninstaller. I have a exe file I want to executable to keep track of the installation and uninstallations. The exe is really simple and sends a message to a server.

```
[Files]
Source: "Tracker\LocalSandboxInstallTracker.exe"; DestDir: "{app}/Tracker";
Source: "Tracker\LocalSandboxInstallTracker.exe.config"; DestDir: "{app}/Tracker";
Source: "Tracker\Tracker.Client.dll"; DestDir: "{app}/Tracker";

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\Tracker\LocalSandboxInstallTracker.exe"; Parameters: " {#MyAppVersion} install"; Flags: runhidden; StatusMsg: "Sending tracking data..."

[Code]
procedure InitializeUninstallProgressForm();
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  Exec ('{app}\Tracker\LocalSandboxInstallTracker.exe',' {#MyAppVersion} uninstall','',SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
end;
```

The call at the installation works well, but not at the uninstall. I placed a breakpoint to my Exec command and it really goes through there, but the exe does not seem to be called.

Comment: What returns the `Exec` function, True or False ? What's the value of the `ResultCode` after this call ?

Comment: The ResultCode is 0 before the Exec, and 267 after.

Comment: You do realize that the app is going to trigger malware/spyware software and firewalls, right? And that the fact you're doing so with `runhidden` looks very suspicious? I for one would advise people not to install it, because it looks like possibly malicious behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must expand the `{app}` constant before passing it to the `Exec` script function. Use the [`ExpandConstant`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_expandconstant.htm) whenever you need to get the value of the constant. Modify your script this way:

```
Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}\Tracker\LocalSandboxInstallTracker.exe'), 
  '{#MyAppVersion} uninstall', '', SW_SHOW, 
  ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

Also, you should check the function result and the output result code to react when the `Exec` function fails. The error code you'll get in the `ResultCode` you can check against the [`System Error Codes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes) reference or use `SysErrorMessage(ResultCode)` to get the error description from script.

Comment: Great, it works. error 267 = invalid directory name, it was appropriate.

Comment: Exactly! To be honest, I've overlooked that too on the first view. When you told me the error code, I've immediately realized there's something wrong with the directory.

Comment: Also note that you should be calling this from `CurUninstallStepChanged(usUninstall)`, as this is when the actual uninstallation actually begins.  (Prior to this there is a chance that it can be cancelled.)  Also also note that there is probably no need to use `ExpandConstant` on `{#MyAppVersion}`, as this is expanded at compile time instead of runtime.  (You only need it if the expansion itself produces runtime-expansion-required values.)

Comment: Good point about `CurUninstallStepChanged(usUninstall)`. And yes, `ExpandConstant` is not needed for preprocessor defines, they are of course expanded by the preprocessor itself.

Answer (score 4):

You have to call the ExpandConstant function if you want to use constants like `{app}` in your Exec call:

```
[Code]
procedure InitializeUninstallProgressForm();
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  Exec (ExpandConstant('{app}\Tracker\LocalSandboxInstallTracker.exe')
    ,' {#MyAppVersion} uninstall','',SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
end;
```

Other way, you're failing to locate the exe.